# Python cannot access list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "black"]
for color in range(0,len(colors)):
    print(color[index])
```

Wondering why I am getting an error when trying to print color index and not sure how to fix or what to change, thanks

Comment: Because `color` is an integer, and you access it as if its a list

Comment: So how might I go about fixing this error?

Comment: `for color in range(0,len(colors)):
    print(colors[color])`

Comment: try enumerate() might help you. Also would suggest you go through python basic concepts once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because color is an integer, and you access it as if its a list.

You should probably wanted to access the `color` from `colors` like the following:

```
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "black"]
for color in range(0,len(colors)):
    print(colors[color])
```

The better way is to iterate over the `colors` list like:

```
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "black"]
for color in colors:
    print(color)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, what is the difference between the first approach and the second approach? Just wondering the different methods

Comment: I will but I can't until after 2 minutes there is a time limit between when you can accept

Comment: @ForgeMods the difference is, that in the first option you access different list element based on the index of the loop, while the other just iterate the list directly and each iteration is a different element from the list. They are basically the same but in python you will prefer the second option

Comment: @ForgeMods see the following link to get more info https://towardsdatascience.com/python-basics-iteration-and-looping-6ca63b30835c

Answer (score 0):

I think you were trying to write `colors` not `color`

You can Try this

```py
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "black"]
map(print, colors)
```

It will do what you were trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "black"]
for color in range(0,len(colors)):`
    print(color)       #This will print the index 
    
#refer below code if you want to print index with the value    
for color in range(0,len(colors)):
    print('Index value is '+str(color)+' and its value is '+str(colors[color]))


I think this is what you want to achieve
```